# Почему не работает border-radius

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qprogressbar

[image: фото]

Почему не работает `border-radius` на прогресс бар? Вроде работает на других виджетах, а тут нет.

```
QProgressBar{
background-color: rgb(98, 114, 164);
color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
border-style:  none;


text-align: center
}

QProgressBar::chunk{

border-radius: 10 px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.545, x2:1, y2:0.54, stop:0 rgba(254, 121, 199, 255), stop:1 rgba(170, 85, 255, 255));
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот добавил и что-то не идёт..

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите развёрнуто. Приложите фрагмент кода и некоторые замечания.

Comment: Изменил код, посмотрите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `border-radius: 10px;`

```
...
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(98, 114, 164);\n"
"    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
"    border-style: none;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"                              # <----
"    text-align: center;\n"
"}\n"
"QProgressBar::chunk{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.511364, x2:1, y2:0.523, stop:0 rgba(254, 121, 199, 255), stop:1 rgba(170, 85, 255, 255));\n"
"}")
...
```

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_SplashScreen(object):
    def setupUi(self, SplashScreen):
        SplashScreen.setObjectName("SplashScreen")
        SplashScreen.resize(680, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SplashScreen)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.dropShadowFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.dropShadowFrame.setStyleSheet("QFrame {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(56, 58, 89);    \n"
"    color: rgb(220, 220, 220);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.dropShadowFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.dropShadowFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.dropShadowFrame.setObjectName("dropShadowFrame")
        self.label_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.label_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 661, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_title.setFont(font)
        self.label_title.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(254, 121, 199);")
        self.label_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName("label_title")
        self.label_description = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.label_description.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 150, 661, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_description.setFont(font)
        self.label_description.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_description.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_description.setObjectName("label_description")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 280, 561, 23))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(98, 114, 164);\n"
"    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
"    border-style: none;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"}\n"
"QProgressBar::chunk{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.511364, x2:1, y2:0.523, stop:0 rgba(254, 121, 199, 255), stop:1 rgba(170, 85, 255, 255));\n"
"}")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.label_loading = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.label_loading.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 320, 661, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_loading.setFont(font)
        self.label_loading.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_loading.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_loading.setObjectName("label_loading")
        self.label_credits = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.label_credits.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 350, 621, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_credits.setFont(font)
        self.label_credits.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(98, 114, 164);")
        self.label_credits.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_credits.setObjectName("label_credits")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dropShadowFrame)
        SplashScreen.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(SplashScreen)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SplashScreen)

    def retranslateUi(self, SplashScreen):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SplashScreen.setWindowTitle(_translate("SplashScreen", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_title.setText(_translate("SplashScreen", "<strong>YOUR</strong> APP NAME"))
        self.label_description.setText(_translate("SplashScreen", "<strong>APP</strong> DESCRIPTION"))
        self.label_loading.setText(_translate("SplashScreen", "loading..."))
        self.label_credits.setText(_translate("SplashScreen", "<strong>Created</strong>: Wanderson M. Pimenta"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    SplashScreen = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_SplashScreen()
    ui.setupUi(SplashScreen)
    SplashScreen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что вы изменили? Я сам делаю по видео Вандерсона.

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер sorry, вы не можете сравнить? Добавил `border-radius: 10px;`

Comment: Так ведь, я же тоже его использовал

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер я добавил обновление в ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Сделал как вы, выше прикрепил скрин, посмотрите, только правый угол закруглился